# How to open the default GUI text editor in Ubuntu or Lubuntu via a script?

Tags: lubuntu, scripts, gedit, default-programs

I have a script that uses gedit to open text file in Ubuntu. That script does not work under Lubuntu. What command is required to execute the default text editor?

I want to make the script usable under Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Comment: Do you have gedit installed in lubuntu?

Comment: no, i do not have gedit installed in lubuntu

Comment: i got gedit by default on ubuntu 14

Answer (score 15):

Use xdg-open it works in most linux distros.
example:

```
xdg-open /filepath/file.txt
```

Comment: Of all the answers, this method just works.

Answer (score 5):

You might get somewhere with `/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor`, as that's set using the alternatives system and points to the default editor under a gnome-ish environment. Not quite sure whether it is actually useful under lubuntu/kubuntu, but you could try.

---

Just to supplement Dennis' answer, with respect to Lubuntu 12.10, if one runs `sudo update-alternatives --display gnome-text-editor`, the output is:

```
gnome-text-editor - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/leafpad
/usr/bin/leafpad - priority 40
  slave gnome-text-editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/leafpad.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/leafpad'.
```

And, as Dennis suggested, `/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor` does open Leafpad in Lubuntu.

Comment: it works under lubuntu. system does not allow me to accept your answer. it says I have to wait. the .... system

Answer (score 4):

Or you can install gedit

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then:

1. Right-click a text or php file
2. Select "Properties"
3. Select "Open with" tab
4. Choose among the listed/installed text editors
5. Click "Set as default"
6. Click "Close"

Comment: but you need the superuser password to install any new software, and it requires a internet connection. Not something you want in a "general" script.

Comment: You only have to do this one time. Then you can execute your script normally

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dennis Kaarsemaker's answer, you could try using `/usr/bin/editor` for something even more generic. This will likely lead to a terminal-based editor be launched, though.

Cf. the [update-alternatives manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html).

Comment: The `update-alternatives --config editor` doesn't list any GUI text editors unfortunately.

Comment: Hence the "This will likely lead to a terminal-based editor be launched, though." I forgot to mention `update-alternatives --config editor`, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_applications) is a list of `Lubuntu` Apps. However, in [`18.10`](https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/) the editor has changed from `Leafpad` to `Featherpad`.

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu 20.04 the default terminal text editor is **vi**:  Here is a guide on how to use **vi**. [How to use vi text editor on Lubuntu](http://lubuntuhowto.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-use-vi-text-editor-on-lubuntu.html)

Here is an example of using **vi** in a terminal (or script):

```
vi /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your script you can simply make a bunch of if blocks that checks for some of the most popular gui editors. Once one is found set a variable to it. Arrange the if blocks to have the ones you'd prefer at the bottom, so it'll overwrite the variable with the last one it finds.

Note that this only works if the gui editors are set on the PATH.

```
#!/bin/bash

# determine which gui text editor is installed
installed_editor="Unknown"

if [[ $(which xed | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
then
    installed_editor="xed"
fi

if [[ $(which mousepad | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
then
    installed_editor="mousepad"
fi

if [[ $(which gedit | wc -l) -ne 0 ]]
then
    installed_editor="gedit"
fi

if [[ "$installed_editor" != "Unknown" ]]
then
    $("$installed_editor")
else
    echo "Couldn't determine default GUI text editor."
fi
```

Hope this helps!